# How to prevent particles from spawning on its emiter's edges?

Tags: particles

[image]

For example here you can see the highlighted particles are spawned on the edges of the emitter.
How to prevent this ?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a plane object,
[image]

then **a border to restrict the particles** can be added by pressing <kbd>I</kbd> once to inset the face(s), adjust the border as to how big you need it. Then press <kbd>I</kbd> once more and add another border close to the first one. This is needed for the weighting to have some space to change from 1 to 0, as otherwise a single face loop border would have a gradient from inner(1) to outer(0) resulting in particles still spawning there.

[image]

With the inner face(s) selected, switch to **weight paint** mode and make sure the **Weight** is set to **1**:
[image]
Now with the mouse over the 3D-Viewport, press **<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>** to set the inner face(s) to a value of **1**.
[image]
By default the weight is **0**, so the outer border should look like in the picture above.
With the **weighting** done, all you need to do is go in the **ParticleSettings** under **Vertex Groups** and select the (with the weight painting) created **Group** in the **Density** field.

[image]

Happy Blending